# pvc clamps keep snapping

Tags: electrical

I live in a cold climate and every winter the metal clamps ( attached to brick) on my 2 1/2 inch pvc underground feed pipe keeps breaking at the side of the house. Can I  assume that the pipe is lifting and eventually snaps the screws ? 
Is there a way of repairing this ?

If so,  will this require  some sort  of sliding  pvc sleeve ? If any one knows of a solution can you please let me know how one can repair this?
Thanks

Comment: Even though your description is fairly good it would help a lot if you could post a nice clear picture.

Comment: where on the run should this be installed ? Note  the pvc pipe is in concrete   so between the meter base and the ground I have 5.5 feet of conduit . If I can install this sleeve   can I install it in between the 5.5 feet ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are expansion joints available

This is an example of a expansion joint

[image]

Www.homedepot.com

You also need to make sure that there is enough wire inside to allow for expansion.

Comment: The clamps are breaking not the pipe, the expansion joints are normally for heat expansion issues.

Comment: Yes so clamp the section that is not moving.

Comment: The conduit should have been installed with a telescoping section to accommodate expansion/contraction cycles due to seasonal changes in temperature. I will take a guess and say this conduit was installed in the hot summer weather. And it also probably faces the hot sun. The electrical code has a chart and a formula for when an exapnsion (telescoping) pipe fitting should be installed. By the way, PVC clamps should never be screwed down all the way to the wall; there must be room to allow for the pipe to slide easily back and forth during exp./contr. cycling.